# Query HTTR GET Request R

Tags: r, rest, url, get, httr

I am connecting via Rest API fine but I cannot query the data in my GET request

```
connectServer <- "https://randompage.com"
apiPrefix <- "/rest/v5/Accounts"
authHeader <- add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer",apiKey))
```

I want to filter on a field called "name" so I'm extracting on a specific name

```
params <- sprintf('name:"Jane Doe" AND language:en')
encoded_params <- urltools::url_encode(params)
```

```
response <- GET(
  paste0(connectServer, apiPrefix), authHeader,
  query = list("name" = I(encoded_params)))
```

Should I be working with the prefix to change the url that was or am I on the right track using the HTTR query functionality? I can obviously filter this with dpylr after i get the response but i'm just trying to build a more efficient GET statement so i'm not bringing in the entire module.

If I remove the query part of the code I have no issues pulling in the data.

Comment: what happens if you do `query = list(name = "Jane Doe", language = "en")`?

Comment: No go; status is still "200 ok". Adding verbose into the command i can see that it's passing that parameter through GET its just not affecting the response.

Comment: Have you confirmed there is a "Jane Doe" record to return?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API documentation?

Comment: I am able to name parameters working if i use:

apiPrefix <- "/rest/v5/Accounts?filter[0][last_name][$equals]=Doe"

Comment: Without any api documentation this is difficult to address. Based on your last response it seems like you would wish to do `query = list("filter[0][last_name][$equals]" = "Doe")`